# how to share a record to particular user

Tags: sharing-rule, apex-sharing

there is a lookup field with User object 
UserLookup__c :
when the field is not empty , share that particular record to selected user in the lookup field.
how can we achieve this
1. I think we can create a criteria based sharing rule: if it is correct please tell me how we can give the criteria.
2. if it is possible with apex sharing how can we achieve this. pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criteria based sharing rule: this is possible, but then you need one rule per possible user. So depending on the org size, this is probably not manageable.

Apex sharing: create a process on the object, and whenever UserLookup__c gets filled in, create a UserLookup__share record for that specific user with the level of access you want to give (read/edit). A great example can be found [here](https://automationchampion.com/tag/prcoess-builder-based-record-sharing-in-salesforce/).